# Close Photoswipe window on swipe down

Tags: event-handling, gesture, photoswipe

This question is a bit specific, but I have implemented the Photoswipe (http://www.photoswipe.com) image gallery and would like to close the full-screen viewer when the user swipes down.

There are already events for swiping left and right that are associated with viewing the previous/next image and a close button that has the same functionality that I am looking for.

Swipe down = close full screen viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the uncompressed code.photoswipe-x.x.x.js. Find the the function onUILayerTouch, which handles the different gestures. In here you add a case, just as swipeRight or swipeLeft:

```
case Util.TouchElement.ActionTypes.swipeUp:
    this.destroyZoomPanRotate();
    this.hide();
    this.toggleToolbar();
    break;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried adding this case before asking the question and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have something to add that isn't precisely connected to the OP's question but I figure it's still relevant.

I was looking for a way to disable PhotoSwipe close on verticalDrag and here is how i disabled it.

```
var options = {
    closeOnVerticalDrag: false,
    //...
}
```

Also note that that this functionality is disabled when using the mouse, refer to:

http://photoswipe.com/documentation/options.html

> Close gallery when dragging vertically and when image is not zoomed. Always false when mouse is used.